# не понимаю как исправить ошибку: "Ошибка времени выполнения: Попытка считывания за концом текстового файла"

Tags: pascalabc.net

дана следующая задача:
А. Создать файл, содержащий сведения о личной коллекции книголюба. Структура записи - шифр книги, автор, название, год издания, местоположение (номер стеллажа, шкафа и т.д.). Количество записей - произвольное.
Б. Найти:

1. местонахождение книги автора Х названия Y;
2. список книг автора Z, находящихся в коллекции;
3. число книг издания ХХ года, имеющееся в библиотеке.
   Значения Х, Y, Z, XX ввести с клавиатуры

   program p3;

   ```
    type
      Book = record
        code: integer;
        author: string;
        title: string;
        year: integer;
        loc: string;
      end;

    var
      collection: array [1..100] of Book;
      authorX, titleY, authorZ: string;
      total, yearXX, i, cnt: integer;
      flag: boolean;
      f: text;

    begin
      assign(f, 'bookCollection.txt');
      reset(f);

      total := 1;

      while not eof(f) do
    begin
      if total < 100 then 
      begin
        readln(f, collection[total].code, collection[total].author, collection[total].title, collection[total].year, collection[total].loc); // *****{----тут ошибка----}
        if (collection[total].code <> 0) and (collection[total].author <> '') and (collection[total].title <> '') and (collection[total].year <> 0) and (collection[total].loc <> '') then
        begin
          total := total + 1;
        end;
      end
      else
      begin
        writeln('Array is full. Increase the size of the "collection" array.');
        break;
      end;
    end;

      close(f);

      writeln('input author X: ');
      readln(authorX);
      writeln('input title Y: ');
      readln(titleY);
      writeln('input author Z: ');
      readln(authorZ);
      writeln('input year ХХ: ');
      readln(yearXX);

      flag := false;
      cnt := 0;

      for i := 1 to total do
      begin
        if (collection[i].author = authorX) and (collection[i].title = titleY) then
        begin
          writeln('book location: ', collection[i].loc);
          flag := true;
        end;

        if collection[i].author = authorZ then
          writeln('authors book ', authorZ, ': ', collection[i].title);

        if collection[i].year = yearXX then
          cnt := cnt + 1;
      end;

      writeln('count books of ', yearXX, ' year: ', cnt);

    end.
   ```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос описание работы кода.